# How to prepare a lecture?

Tags: software-industry, communication, meetings, training

How should I plan an oral, technical presentation to colleagues? It will be my first.

If I started to just record myself at home, begin to talk and see what happens ... that would be experimental, and there's probably a better or more structured way to do it?

Maybe I should treat it as a "technical writing" assignment to begin with -- develop a table of contents, write text for each section, read it aloud -- but on the day I suppose I shouldn't read off a teleprompter and should only have a PowerPoint deck.

I'm completely inexperienced so I don't know what to ask.

- How should I plan to do it
- Are there intermediate steps in the planning
- How do you go about it
- Would you recommend any tutorials, reference materials, or examples

---

Background

I've been asked to give an "oral presentation" at work.

It's a formal HR "goal" for this year: for professional development i.e. to improve or practice my communication skills.

It will be 30 to 45 minutes; the audience and I are software developers; and the subject, I will introduce some software projects, which I wrote as a hobby at home (perhaps one in-depth, or highlights of three).

I am a senior developer but I have never before given or planned a public talk, i.e. only ever unscripted dialog.

Comment: I see two Close votes for "needs more focus" i.e. "focus on one problem only". My one problem here is that I must prepare a 45-minute oral presentation for work, and though I know the subject I have never prepared a lecture, so I don't know how to do that or plan how to accomplish that.

Comment: The fact that Kate wrote a useful answer suggests that the question is answerable, if someone has experience with it.

Comment: I also believe this needs more focus.  The question "how do I give a presentation" is very broad and, as noted in one of the answers, there are entire books on the topic.

Comment: Ask your manager if there are any prerecorded lectures to serve as a good example for you to follow, or to speak to someone who gave a well received lecture for tips.  As it stands, the question you are asking is way to broad.  50 people can give 50 different answers and they all could be correct or not, as we do not know what your company is expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a HUGE topic suitable for a book. But I will give you some tips.

First, do not script the entire talk word for word and then read that. This is almost never the right approach.

When I do a talk, I create a powerpoint for the attendees to see and speaker notes for me to see. These have more detail and some specific wordings that I need to remember. For example, the powerpoint might say

**Considerations**

- price
- delivery date
- security

And then your notes might expand on those a little bit, for example "cheapest is $X, most expensive is $Y". Or maybe that's on the slide, but the notes explain some other aspect or provide some other details. While you're rehearsing, those notes will ensure you don't forget what you wanted to say. They are also a backup if you freeze on stage.

As for how to create this deck, it's iterative. Some of my talks have started as just me talking "to know what I think" and later I've written the deck. It's more common to write a sort of outline deck, not very detailed, then try talking to it, add slides, move things around, create a diagram or a technical demo that I will run during the talk, try talking to it again, and so on until the length is right, I've covered what I'm supposed to cover, and I'm comfortable delivering it.

I've been doing this for over 20 years and I've spoken on 5 continents. (You can see many of [my talks](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLsAtvvJ8KXBT-Tx67H5P3TgkiW6llnoBE) online.) Preparing a talk is real work, not something you toss together in an afternoon. Expect to put some real time in on this.

The matter of actually delivering the talk is another huge topic of its own. The most important thing is to practice doing it. To actually stand up with your laptop in presentation mode and your speaker notes showing, make a note of the time, and do the whole talk. Use the clicker to advance the slides, everything. (I wear different glasses when I'm speaking than when I am at my desk very close to my screen. I rehearse standing up with those glasses on.) Then to adjust it, and another day, to do that again. It won't be the same every time, and that's fine. Nothing wrong with that. When you do it "for real" it will be right for the day.

You may want to watch other people's talks to see some of how it's done. But a 45 minute "some of my projects you might want to know about" talk at work is not a conference talk. Finding user group talks online might be more useful.

Comment: `Expect to put some real time in on this.` I agree. Here in France now, unlike in Canada, in theory I shouldn't work overtime, and so if this is a work assignment, then it's one or more Tasks, to be scheduled. I think you're right, that it's more than an afternoon. If it's like our other dev tasks, I should estimate the work -- "I need to do this, and that, and then the other, which will take X, Y, and Z days or hours respectively". If I've never done this kind of work before, and don't have a plan for each step (each activity and result, what and how) so it's hard to define and execute. :-)

Comment: Thank you for the tips. That's insight into the goal and the process. The goal is a deck with notes, and experience with speaking to them. The process is iteratively: start with a written outline; develop the details by "talking to it" (whatever that means); codify the details, by writing notes and further slides; then run-through or rehearse, measuring the duration and revising the sequence. And the definition of "done" is when I can deliver it comfortably.

Comment: "talking to it" is less than a rehearsal. Put up the slide, sitting at your desk, in edit mode not in presentation mode, and start saying stuff you might say when that slide is up. Edit the slide. Add a bullet. Split a slide into two. Scrap stuff because it's a rabbit hole. Hear yourself and you'll know what you're trying to say - you'll put that on the slides or in the notes.

Comment: I'll try that. A last question if I may, why did you say that a conference talk and a user group talk are not the same, what's the important difference (e.g. in the talk itself or in how it's prepared)?

Comment: audience size makes a difference. Room size, is there a stage, are you using a mike, how big is the screen, all make a difference. Also, peer to peer is not the same as expert to room of learners - there's a spectrum and ug and conference are at different places on it. Generally a talk at work is less formal, less of a lecture and more of a chat. You still prep a ton, it's just you choose less formal words, you maybe take questions on the fly, you might make in jokes you wouldn't do with strangers, that sort of thing.